# Multiple-Slit Interference: Secondary Maxima Clarification

Tags: double-slit-experiment

[image]

I am not sure what to be looking for when **observing the secondary maxima** of a multiple slit interference. What does it mean when secondary maxima occurs (n-2) evenly spaced positions between the principal maxima?

Comment: [Hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/gratint.html#c1) has an excellent page about this. Note for multiple slit diffraction, there are (N-2) smaller peaks between the major peaks

Comment: Thank you for the clarification